# Copy the text of a cell after an hyperlink click to another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink

I have a list and all the text is hyperlinked to the same cell in the same sheet.

Is there any way to copy the text of the cell you've clicked to the other cell?

```
  A                                                                B
=HYPERLINK("...range=B1";"apple")                                                           
=HYPERLINK("...range=B1";"banana")
=HYPERLINK("...range=B1";"pear")
=HYPERLINK("...range=B1";"melon")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to click/select a cell and get the value copied to the next cell in the same row.

- You can use a [onSelectionChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) trigger to achieve your goal.

### Solution:

Copy this code to the script editor:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) { 
  if(e.range.getColumn()==1){
     e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(e.range.getValue());
  }
}
```

**Illustration:**

[image]

**Updated code based on OPs comment:**

Copy all hyperlinks to cell `B1`:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) { 
  if(e.range.getColumn()==1){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('B1').setValue(e.range.getValue());
  }
}
```

**Please Note!**

Users have reported in the [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180042705) that `onSelectionChange` trigger does not work for them and it didn't work for me either. However, after I tried the recommendation steps by the google guy (you can find them in the link also) it worked:

> However, I managed to get the trigger to work correctly by
> deactivating V8 runtime, closing the Apps Script project and the
> document, and finally, reopening the document and reactivating the V8
> runtime.

Comment: Thanks! Can it be posible to copy the values to the same cell, for example to B1?

Comment: Do you mean A1? @AntorCha If yes, then remove the offset `e.range.setValue(e.range.getValue());` If you mean `B1`, then this is what the code does already. Let me know if I miss anything.

Comment: I mean hyperlink the whole list to the same cell, A1 to B1, A2 to B1, A3 to B1... Each time replacing the value in the B1 cell with the new one. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @AntorCha thanks for the clarification. Please check my updated answer (**Updated code based on OPs comment**) part and consider accepting the answer if it solved your question